# php syntax error, quote marks

Tags: php, syntax-error, epub

I have this piece of code that causes my script to crash. I'm certain that there is some kind of quote mark confusion on my part. Have been staring at this for an hour now and can't find the error. Any help much appreciated.

The `$title` can include commas, could that be it? Removing all variables fixes the issue, maybe it's an issue with how I'm adding them or what they contain?

```
$contentopf = "
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<package xmlns=\"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf\" unique-identifier=\"bookid\" version=\"3.0\" prefix=\"rendition: http://www.idpf.org/vocab/rendition/# ibooks: http://vocabulary.itunes.apple.com/rdf/ibooks/vocabulary-extensions-1.0/\">
  <metadata xmlns=\"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" >
     <dc:format>application/epub+zip</dc:format>
     <meta name=\"cover\" content=\"cover-image\" />
     <dc:title>".$title."</dc:title>
     <meta property=\"ibooks:version\">0.3.0</meta>
     <dc:creator id=\"aut\">".$fname." ".$lname"</dc:creator>
     <meta refines=\"#aut\" property=\"role\" scheme=\"marc:relators\">aut</meta>
     <meta refines=\"#aut\" property=\"file-as\">".$lname.", ".$fname"</meta>
     <dc:description>!</dc:description>
     <dc:publisher>".$publisher."</dc:publisher>
     <dc:date>".$year."</dc:date>
     <dc:language>".$lang."</dc:language>
     <dc:identifier id='bookid'>urn:uuid:".$uuid."</dc:identifier>
     <meta refines='#bookid' property='identifier-type' scheme='xsd:string'>uuid</meta>
     <dc:identifier id='isbn-id'>urn:isbn:".$isbn."</dc:identifier>
     <meta refines='#isbn-id' property='identifier-type' scheme='onix:codelist5'>15</meta>
     <meta property=\"dcterms:modified\">".$date."</meta>
     <meta property=\"rendition:layout\">pre-paginated</meta>
     <meta property=\"rendition:orientation\">landscape</meta>
     <meta property=\"rendition:spread\">none</meta>
     <meta property=\"ibooks:specified-fonts\">true</meta>
     <meta property='ibooks:iphone-orientation-lock'>landscape-only</meta>                                     
     <meta property='ibooks:ipad-orientation-lock'>landscape-only</meta>                          
</metadata>
";

echo $contentopf;
```

Comment: There are less error prone ways of creating XML in PHP. See: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php for example (there are libraries that provide simpler APIs still)

Comment: for degugging page, setup apache and php so that it prints errors (on developement environment) and also use some javascript debugger like firebug or chrome developer tool to catch js errors.

Comment: @jimmy have you checked the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `.` here

```
".$fname"</meta>
```

should be

```
".$fname."</meta>
```

here also

```
".$lname."</dc:creator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing dot here :

```
 <meta refines=\"#aut\" property=\"file-as\">".$lname.", ".$fname"</meta>
```

should be

```
<meta refines=\"#aut\" property=\"file-as\">".$lname.", ".$fname."</meta>
```

PS : you should really think switching to an alternative like printf(), that uses placeholders.